How do I expose the current logged in users name/etc to javascript?
Currently using a Javascript API for he first time to our woocommerce site. We have installed a chat (Social Intents) which provided us with a code to collect data from the person chatting with us. The shop is for logged in members only, so the info is already collected once the customer registers and logs in.
<script type="text/javascript">
function onSIApiReady() 
{
//Will display the tab once the scripts have loaded
SI_API.setChatInfo('visitor name','email@test.com','(123) 123-1234',
'Marketing','I have a question about your products');
};
</script>

In backend it says "visitor name" and "email@test.com" aswell, so my question is: what do I have to write instead to make it fetch the correct data from the user and not just copy whats in the code?

note that while Social Intents and WooCommerce are both out of scope and offtopic here, this offtopic question could be brought on topic if you simplified and instead asked "How do I expose the current logged in users name/etc to javascript?". This would give you what you need to fix your problem without needing any specialist knowledge in WooCommerce and Social Intents.

You can use wp_localize_script() to pass data from WordPress/PHP to a registered script. (This means you'll need to use wp_register_script() and/or wp_enqueue_script() to add the script to your site.)
